# How to prove $x^{\phi(m)+1}\equiv x\pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, congruences

How do I prove that $x^{\phi(m)+1}\equiv x\pmod{p}$ when $m=pq$, two distinct primes? I kind of have an idea that it involves Euler's Theorem but it doesn't seem to be working as well as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

$$\phi(m)=\phi(pq)=\phi(p)\phi(q)$$
Hence $x^{\phi(m)+1}={(x^{\phi(p)})}^{\phi(q)}x^1$; the result now follows by [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) or [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem), assuming $p\nmid x$.  If $p|x$, of course, both sides are zero modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's theorem says $x^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$, which implies $$x^{\phi(m)+1} = x^{\phi(m)}x \equiv 1x \equiv x \pmod m.$$ 
Now, $p$ divides $m$, and $m$ divides $x^{\phi(m)+1}-x$, so by transitivity of divisibility, $p$ divides $x^{\phi(m)+1} - x$, which is to say $x^{\phi(m)+1}\equiv x \pmod p$.

**Update**:
Euler's theorem can only be applied if $x$ and $m$ are coprime. If $d = \gcd(x, m)$ isn't $1$, then it's one of $\{p, q, m\}$. If $d=q$, we're set: 
$$x^{\phi(m)} = \left(x^{p-1}\right)^{q-1} \equiv 1^{q-1} = 1 \pmod p$$
by Fermat's little theorem, and the result follows on multiplying by $x$.

If $d = p$ or $m$, then $p \mid d \mid x$ implies $x \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and so, obviously, $x^{\phi(m)+1} \equiv 0 \equiv x \pmod p$.

Comment: Euler's theorem, as usually quoted, requires that $x$ is coprime to $m$.

Comment: Good call. I'll update the answer.